# Spring Kafka Stop container on Exception

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` with auto commit set to false to consume messages from the topic and write to Database. If Database is down I need to stop the container from processing current record in a poll and don't do next `poll()`. I have implemented `DataSourceHealthIndicator` and after checking Database status to UP I want to restart my container again to process remaining records.

Any suggestion how can I stop processing remaining records and stop the container, I have tried to use `consumer.close()`. But it doesn't stop the process and kept throwing consumer is already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `container.stop()`. If you are using `@KafkaListener`s, call `stop()` on the listener container registry which will stop all registered containers.

**EDIT**

Error handlers for [automatically stopping the container](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/d2ce4aba1e68de9e97a63cb0052f7c83e90e40c2) have been available since the 2.1 release; at the time of writing the current version is 2.2.3.

Comment: The container is not available to an AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener  only consumer is available

Comment: Not via the listener method, true, but you can autowire it or otherwise inject it; you should probably not call stop() on the listener thread, though, because it will cause a shutdown delay.

Comment: I have used `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` that is pretty much same as you suggested.

Comment: @GaryRussell you have done a great job on [spring-kafka container stoping feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/451). Updating your answer will also help a lot of people to use `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler`.